# Error in creating horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android

I am working in android, i want to make a scrollview. 
this is my code for that :

```
package com.pericent;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloTabWidget extends Activity  {

    private String TAG="HelloTabWidget";



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Log.v(TAG,"i am just before everything");
        HorizontalScrollView hr=new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        hr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout mainlayout=new LinearLayout(this);
        mainlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.upper1);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        Log.v(TAG,"i am just after the declarations");
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            TextView txt=new TextView(this);
            txt.setText("Text " + i );
            layout.addView(txt);
        }
        Log.v(TAG,"i am after the for loop");
        hr.addView(layout);

        mainlayout.addView(hr);//<<---this is creating NullPointerException
        setContentView(R.layout.cecking);
        Log.v(TAG,"i am after the everything");

  }
}
```

and this my cecking.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/upper1">

</LinearLayout>
```

whenever i run the program, this error is occurred:-

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pericent/com.pericent.HelloTabWidget}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

and in this line the error is occurred:- **mainlayout.addView(hr);**

please help me to find out the reason of error.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting any layout for the Activity
as well as you are not Inflating checking.xml for that Activity.
That's why mainlayout cannot be found and cause `NullPointerException`
Try this way:
checking.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/upper1">
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then set your layout inside `onCreate()` of the `Activity`
like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContenView(R.layout.checking);
        mainlayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.upper1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir... i have done this by taking your help. actually i have done mistake, i didnt write this line :-this.setContenView(R.layout.checking); Thank you again...

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you haven't set

```
.setLayoutParams(new Layout...
```

for mainlayout, the error statement line object.

Comment: no sir this is not cause, because in xml i have declared these properties for this mainlayout.

Comment: Thanks Mike Gates, using short keys is such a curse. :(